# goto statement leading to an infinite loop

Tags: c, goto

We were having a quiz of sorts and had the following question where we had to find the error, or if there's none, the output of the given code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int n = 012;

  b: printf("%d\n",n--);

  if(n!=0){
    n--;
    goto b;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

I don't see anything wrong with this in theory but this leads to an infinite loop with the variable going way below 0. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: What did you learn debugging?  Did you intend to decrement `n` in two places?

Comment: Use paper and pencil to step through the code and track the value of `n`. It will only take a minute. You'll see why the test `n != 0` doesn't stop the looping. Note that the literal `012` is an **octal** value.

Comment: Why are you using `goto`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful

Comment: iteration will print n for indexes, 10,8,6,4,2,0 , after print inside printf we are decrementing the n by 1. when n reach if statement , it will be 9, 7,5,3,1,-1. and the termination condition n==0 will never hit.  if the intention is to print "10,8,6,4,2,0 " , change the termination condition from  " if(n!=0){ " to "if(n>0){".

Comment: @EdHeal: Learn `goto` so you can use it. Error handling in C without `goto` is not fun.

Comment: @Joshua - In my career as a C programmer I never need to use `goto` for error handling. Some of those were complex systems (e.g. for a power station)

Comment: @EdHeal: How do you handle multiple cleanup steps and multiple failure points?

Comment: Use of early returns from a function, if statements. There are plenty of techniques that do not require `goto` and I would submit that these techniques make it easier to ensure that the code is correct. One reason (and a very good one IMHO) is answering the question "how did you get to the goto label?) Might be easy to answer when the code is written but after a long period of maintenance it gets harder to check.

Comment: The takeaway from the "quiz" is: never write code like that!

Answer (score 1):

You should only have one n-- statement. otherwise even if it reaches 0, when it get the first n-- it will be decremented one more time and will become -1. (so it will never match 0).

Hence, please change your code to

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int n = 012;

  b: printf("%d\n",n--);

  if(n!=0){
   goto b;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int n = 012;

  b: printf("%d\n",n);

  if(n!=0){
    n--;
    goto b;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

This would work. The version you posted does not work because it will never get to 0. It is subtracting once in the `if` statement, and once in the `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

**The condition  `if (n != 0)` is always getting satisfied.**

On each iteration the number `n` decreases by 2.

So when n = 2, it gets decremented once after `printf("%d\n",n--)`

then the condition `if (n != 0)` is true, as `n = 1`

Inside the condition block `n` is decremented once again, `n = 0`

So the next time before reaching the condition `if (n != 0)`, `n` equals to -1,

which leads to an infinite loop.

Comment: As n is decremented twice, the if condition only sees odd numbers when n starts out as even number. If n starts out as an odd number, the if condition only sees even numbers and the iteration ends.

Answer (score 0):

In C 012 is an octal base number, in decimal it is equal to 10.

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int n = 012;

  b: printf("%d\n",n--);

  if(n!=0){
    n--;
    goto b;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Does this:

```
print n (10)
subtract 1 of n (n = 10 - 1 = 9)
check if n != 0 (9 != 0 -> true)
subtract 1 of n (n = 9 - 1 = 8)
jump to b

print n (8)
subtract 1 of n (n = 8 - 1 = 7)
check if n != 0 (7 != 0 -> true)
subtract 1 of n (n = 7 - 1 = 6)
jump to b

print n (6)
subtract 1 of n (n = 6 - 1 = 5)
check if n != 0 (5 != 0 -> true)
subtract 1 of n (n = 5 - 1 = 4)
jump to b

print n (4)
subtract 1 of n (n = 4 - 1 = 3)
check if n != 0 (3 != 0 -> true)
subtract 1 of n (n = 3 - 1 = 2)
jump to b

print n (2)
subtract 1 of n (n = 2 - 1 = 1)
check if n != 0 (1 != 0 -> true)
subtract 1 of n (n = 1 - 1 = 0)
jump to b

print n (0)
subtract 1 of n (n = 0 - 1 = -1)
check if n != 0 (-1 != 0 -> true)
subtract 1 of n (n = -1 - 1 = -2)
jump to b

print n (-2)
...
...
... goes on infinitely
```

Note that when `n` will never equal to `0` when the program checks if `n != 0`, because in this evaluation `n` is always an odd number since two subtractions by 1 are made every time.

Answer (score 0):

Change from `b: printf("%d\n",n--);` to `b: printf("%d\n",n);`.

or

Change from

```
  if(n!=0){
    n--;
    goto b;
```

to

```
  if(n!=0){
    n;
    goto b;
```

Because `n--` equals `n = n - 1`.

Your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int n = 012;

  b: printf("%d\n",n--); // n = n - 1

  if(n!=0){
    n--; // n = n - 1
    goto b;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for out put [10, 8, 6, 4,2, 0]

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
      int n = 012;

      b: printf("%d\n",n--);

      if(n>0){
        n--;
        goto b;
      }

      return 0;
    }
```

for [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
      int n = 012;

      b: printf("%d\n",n--);

      if(n>0){
        //n--;
        goto b;
      }

      return 0;
    }
```